# Is this a semantically correct question?

Tags: semantics

Is this semantically a good sentence? If it is, can it have a negative meaning?

> You are not gonna set me an appointment up.

Comment: Is it intended to mean "Are you not going to set me up an appointment?"

Comment: Yeah maybe. Actually I don`t know if I misunderstood the question or the other person was a bit condescending.

Comment: Is there a verb like: "set somebody an appointment" at all?

Comment: It's **syntactically** unacceptable according to standard practice, which demands that the particle ('up') should come before the noun phrase 'an appointment', as KillingTime says. Additionally, using 'set up' as a benefactive at all (' .. set me up an appointment') might be seen as borderline acceptable by some. ' ... cook me up a good meal' seems reasonable, at least in an informal register (but again, '... cook me a good meal up' sounds non-standard).

Comment: There are three unnecessary problems with the example sentence. First, it's negative, though the syntactic problem has nothing to do with negation. Second, it's second person, and it sounds aggressive, though once again the syntax doesn't need it. Third, it uses _be going to_, though ... So start with _He set me an appointment up._ Same syntactic structure, fewer distractions. Now there are two movement rules involved here - Dative Alternation flipping the _me_ around, and Particle Shift flipping the _up_ around. They interact in interesting ways, but this is one of the grammatical ones.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!